# What is the execution order of local resolvers in React Apollo?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

Say I have the following query:

```
query Foo {
  foo {
    bar
    baz
    qux @client
  }
}
```

And these resolvers:

```js
Foo: {
  qux: () => {
    console.log("qux");
    return "qux";
  },
  bar: obj => {
    console.log("bar");
    return obj.bar;
  },
  baz: obj => {
    console.log("baz");
    return obj.baz;
  }
}
```

Is the execution order of the resolvers dependent on the order in the query - or the other way around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: there is no "resolver order". The order is given only by the query.

If you run the mock query, this is what gets logged:

```js
bar
baz
qux
```

This is in spite of `qux` being the first declared resolver. You can only have it logged first if you move `qux @client` up above in the query, like this:

```
query Foo {
  foo {
    qux @client
    bar
    baz
  }
}
```

Then the logs would be:

```js
qux
bar
baz
```

Of course, this behaviour may vary depending on what versions you use. Here are mine:

- @apolo/react-hooks@3.1.3
- apollo-cache-inmemory@1.6.3
- apollo-client@2.6.4
- apollo-link-http@1.5.16
- graphql@14.5.8
- graphql-tag@2.10.1